# Problems writing to file in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm currently trying to write an excel file from a file format using the function `tr8 pd.to_excel` of pandas. However, It writes the excel file, but when opening in excel I cannot see the full data. I attached the code of `tr8`

```
output_file = pd.ExcelWriter('20131001103311.xlsx')
widths = [1, 8, 2, 4, 2, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 10, 1]
df = pd.read_fwf('20131001103311.tr8', widths=widths, header=True)
df.columns = ['TIP. REG.', 'COD. EST.', 'TIP. INF.', 'AGNO', 'DEL', 'ENE', 'OBS', 'FEB', 'OBS', 'MAR', 'OBS', 'ABR',
              'OBS', 'MAY', 'OBS', 'JUN', 'OBS', 'JUL', 'OBS', 'AGO', 'OBS', 'SEP', 'OBS', 'OCT', 'OBS', 'NOV', 'OBS',
              'DIC', 'OBS', 'ESP.', 'TIP. DATO']
df.to_excel(output_file, '20131001103311')
output_file.save()
```

Comment: Explain 'cannot see the full data'... what do you see versus what you expect to see?

Comment: Hi and thks for your time. I can send you the files, here will not let me post images or upload files, or not know how. Thks.

Comment: See updated comment below. The issue seems to be related to the multiple `OBS` columns. This *may* be a `pandas` issue and you should create an issue on GitHub with some sample data.

Comment: I've raised an [issue with Pandas](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5235).

Comment: Excelent !!!! Congratulations !!!

Comment: The issue is now fixed on the pandas master branch. See the updates below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simplified your program down to 2 columns of data for testing:

```
import pandas as pd

output_file = pd.ExcelWriter('20131001103311.xlsx')

widths = [10, 10]
df = pd.read_fwf('20131001103311.tr8', widths=widths, header=True)

df.columns = ['TIP. REG.', 'COD. EST.']

df.to_excel(output_file, '20131001103311')
output_file.save()
```

And I ran it against the following fixed width format `fwf` file:

```
$ cat 20131001103311.tr8
TIP. REG. COD. EST.
1         1000
2         300
3         7000
4         600
5         12345
```

I didn't get any execution errors and the output looks like it should:

[image]

The first row of data is missing since the parameter `header=True` has been passed to `read_fwf`.

So it doesn't seem to be an `pandas` issue.

I would look at the columns in your fixed width fields file. Perhaps print it out after reading to see if the column names that you supply to `df.columns` have all been parsed correctly.

**Update**: Looking at the images of the input data and the output file that @jchavarro tried to upload it looks that there may be an issue here. At least the Excel output doesn't tie up with the DataFrame data. Probably due to the repeated `OBS` columns.

**Update 2**: This is an issue. I've raised it on [GitHub and submitted a fix](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5235).

**Update 3**: I created a fix for the above issue which has now been merged into the pandas master branch and which should be released as part of the 0.13 release.